# Uneven Paint Layers

Tags: wood, painting, paint, sanding, wood-filler

I have some spots that look like the wood was scraped and painted without sanding or filling so you can see the different layers / heights. Please recommend grit(s) to use on my random orbital sander to bring it all down to the same level.

Comment: Only you can answer if its acceptable. This question is offtopic  it may get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aesthetics are up to you and off topic.

If you want it smooth, sanding aggressively is probably more likely to be very smooth at the end. Just make sure you don't have lead paint under there. The alternative is to fill with a wood filler and putty knife. How nice you want it will dictate how many passes you do (fill  wait to dry, sand  repeat), which will determine which method is less work.